# Laravel "group by having" query issues

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Please I am trying to run a query that looks like this in raw sql

```
SELECT COUNT(cntr) count, address,
description FROM resti GROUP BY cntr = HAVING count > 1
```

in laravel.

I have tried  this

```
 DB::table("resti")
                 ->select(DB::raw("COUNT(cntr) count, address, description"))
                 ->groupBy("cntr")
                 ->havingRaw("count > 1")
                 ->get();
```

But it gives of some aggregate error.

Comment: Try `toSql()` to see the final query.

Comment: Thanks. Its actually outputting the correct sql. Not sure where the issue might be from. But thanks alot.

Comment: What error message do you have? And where exactly?

Comment: I added a count to the end of the query builder after removing the get() i.e I added ->count() and it prints **select count(*) as aggregate from `resti` group by `cntr` having count > 1** which throws an unknown column error.

Comment: of course, `count > 1` is unknown column.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `SELECT COUNT(cntr) AS count, ...` ??

Comment: Exactly, thats because the same query which outputs properly with ->get() is somehow transformed when replaced with ->count()

Comment: This code is OK. Show errors you get or describe what is not working as expected.

Comment: The code is ok. Apparently PHPMYADMIN was outputting a different result from Laravel. That was what led to me believe that there was an issue with sql query output of Laravel, but alas, that wasnt the case.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your SQL query should be like this

```
SELECT COUNT(cntr) count, address, description 
FROM resti 
GROUP BY cntr  
HAVING COUNT(cntr) > 1
```

In Laravel your code should be like this

```
DB::table("resti")
->select(DB::raw("COUNT(cntr) count, address, description"))
->groupBy("cntr")
->havingRaw("COUNT(cntr) > 1")
->get();
```

Comment: the query adding the value which has not match the "havingRaw" condition, can you help on that?

Comment: @always-a-learner Could you explain more, a code sample or more details!