# How to count the repetition of a single value in a group in laravel 8 and get the value if it exceeds a certain limit?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-8

I want to pick the dates from the 'reservation_date' column if the same column repeats itself X number of times(I'd be using a variable to compare). Something like

```php
$arrayOfDates => Reservations::groupBy('reservation_date')->
```

Now I can't find anywhere on how to select based on the count of the repetition of a value.
Something like

```php
where(count(as count of the items in a group >= $X)->get()
```

Comment: This won't be an eloquent solution but this will help you `\DB::table('topics as lt')->selectRaw('DISTINCT topic,id')->whereRaw('(SELECT COUNT(topic) from laravel.topics as repetetion where `topic`= lt.topic group by topic) > 3')` just replace the columns and table names a per your code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel "group by having" query issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26747740/laravel-group-by-having-query-issues)

Comment: You've [already asked a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70992309/how-to-group-items-in-laravel-and-echo-the-value-if-group-count-is-larger-than-a), so why another one?